# What happens if you call a non constexpr function before a constexpr function

Tags: c++

In my class, a non-constexpr function is called right before a constexpr function. First one cannot be constexpr because it's an API call, but I would like the second one to be evaluated at compile-time.

```
class MyClass
{
...
int m_val = 0;
constepxr void changeval(int newval) { this.m_val = newval; }
...
MyClass()
{
if(WriteProcessMemory(...)
{
this->changeval(12);
}
}
```

So what happens in this scenario? Does changeval get evaluated twice? Is it not hit at all? Is the whole chunk of code including the WPM call skipped?

Comment: Think about what you are asking with `changeval`.  `changeval` *changes* a value, it is the opposite of a constant expression

Comment: How so? The variable can be changed statically trough constexpr, no?

Comment: You should post code that at least compiles. `constepxr` is a typo and `this` doesn't have a `.` operator.

Comment: The code is to represent what my question asks, question which I believe can be answered without code